# how do i override jQuery Cycle's black background injexion?

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

using the following:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle/3.0.3/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
```

anyone know how to override jQuery Cycle plugin's stupid injexion of  `backgound-color: rgb(0,0,0);` INLINE???  if it weren't for the scale of this project, i'd just refactor to something else...  >:(

i've tried doing this *after* the `$('#carousel').cycle()` call, but have had no luck:

```
$('#carousel').cycle({
  fx: 'fade',
      pause: 1,
      next: '#next_btn',
      prev: '#prev_btn',
      speed: 500,
      timeout: 10000,
      cleartype: true,
      cleartypeNoBgG: true
    });
$('.unit').css({'background-color':''});  <--THIS BIT RIGHT HERE
```

also this:

```
$('.unit').css({'background-color':'transparent'});
```

and this:

```
$('.unit').css({'background-color':'none'});
```

i've also tried various CSS manipulations to no effect, likely because INLINE declarations are always processed last (thus the JS attempts because it's directly defined in the element's `<style>`).  :(

this is **NOT** a question of IE7,8 or 9.  this is a pan-browser problem.  and, yes, i've read everything related to those problems, but this isn't a rendering issue.  it's an injexion override issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you had the correct solution in mind, but a typo got in your way.

```
cleartypeNoBgG: true
```

Should have been:

```
cleartypeNoBg: true
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind.  looks like the only solution is to force a particular CSS override.  which is fine.  found the answer elsewhere, so i'm closing this issue.